# How do I read a Windows-1252 file using Rcpp?

Tags: c++, locale, rcpp, windows-1252

I want to force the input format when reading a file into Windows-1252 encoding together with Rcpp. I need this since I switch between Linux/Windows environments and while the files are consistently in 1252 encoding.

How do I adapt this to work:

```
String readFile(std::string path) {
  std::ifstream t(path.c_str());
  if (!t.good()){
    std::string error_msg = "Failed to open file ";
    error_msg += "'" + path + "'";
    ::Rf_error(error_msg.c_str());
  }

  const std::locale& locale = std::locale("sv_SE.1252");
  t.imbue(locale); 
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << t.rdbuf();
  return ss.str();
}
```

The above fails with:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
```

I've also tried with "Swedish_Sweden.1252" that is the default for my system to no avail. I've tried `#include <boost/locale.hpp>` but that seems to be unavailable in Rcpp (v 0.12.0)/BH boost (v. 1.58.0-1).

#### Update:

After digging a little deeper into this I'm not sure if the gcc (v. 4.6.3) in RTools (v. 3.3) is built with locale support, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105167/c-error-failure-localefacet-s-create-c-locale-name-not-valid-when-runni) points to that possibility. If there is any argument except "" or "C" works with std::locale() it would be interesting to know, I've tried a few more alternatives but nothing seems to work.

#### Fallback solution

I'm not entirely satisfied but it seems that using the `base::iconv()` fixes any issues with characters regardless of the original format, much thanks to the `from="WINDOWS-1252"`argument forcing the chars to be interpreted in the correct form, i.e. if we want to stay in Rcpp we can simply do:

```
String readFile(std::string path) {
  std::ifstream t(path.c_str());
  if (!t.good()){
    std::string error_msg = "Failed to open file ";
    error_msg += "'" + path + "'";
    ::Rf_error(error_msg.c_str());
  }

  const std::locale& locale = std::locale("sv_SE.1252");
  t.imbue(locale); 
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << t.rdbuf();
  Rcpp::StringVector ret = ss.str();

  Environment base("package:base");
  Function iconv = base["iconv"];

  ret = iconv(ret, Named("from","WINDOWS-1252"),Named("to","UTF8"));

  return ret;
}
```

Note that it is preferrable to wrap the function in R rather than getting the function from C++ and then calling it from there, it is both less code and improves performance improvement by a factor of 2 (checked with microbenchmark):

```
readFileWrapper <- function(path){
   ret <- readFile(path)
   iconv(ret, from = "WINDOWS-1252", to = "UTF8")
}
```

Comment: Can you try Rcpp 0.12.0 which was just released?  It added some encoding support.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: Thanks, but unfortunately I get the same error. I'm not sure if the syntax is at all correct, i.e. is it any of the above suggested alternatives? As I wrote, there is a [boost::locale](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/locale/doc/html/default_encoding_under_windows.html) that should be built for handling this type of problems, but it seems like the locale isn't included in Windows since I get _fatal error: boost/locale.hpp: No such file or directory_ while other parts load fine (e.g. `#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>`)